# Proper way to put array in UML diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram

I am new to UML diagrams, so this may be a very ignorant question though I can't find the answer anywhere.

There is a class Classroom that holds an object of lecture times. Should lecture times be its own class or should it be an attribute of Classroom?

Feel free to critique notation.

**Edit:** I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459257/how-to-represent-an-attributes-data-type-as-an-array-of-objects-on-class-diagra) and it has not helped. I would like to know if LectureTime should be a separate class.

**Option 1:**
[image: Option 1]

**Option 2:**

[image: Option 2]

Comment: Asked already. [Watch the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459257/how-to-represent-an-attributes-data-type-as-an-array-of-objects-on-class-diagra)

Comment: Thank you for commenting Adir. I have seen that post previously, but I am wondering about the UML design. I would like to know if LectureTime should be a separate class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new class if it has more than a single attribute and/or additional operations (which are not just a getter/setter). Or of you plan to add them in a later phase.

In your case `lectureTime` is obviously a simple type and the 2nd variant is to be preferred, except see above.

However, instead of the round braces you should use square brackets like `validLectureTimes[]` or `validLectureTimes[0..*]` which are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If *LectureTime* is an Entity then yes. I guess it is, because of the relation you've added.